# Access to ECDSA sign inside Runtime

Tags: runtime, benchmark, cryptography

Is there any way to access to ECDSA capabilities (like `sign`) inside the Runtime?

I need to create benchmarks where the parameter of one extrinsic needs to be signed using ECDSA. I could create some 'hosted-functions' to do that, but I think it should be already done for each crypto schema (`ed25519`, `sr25519`, and `ecdsa`).

Answer (score 2):

yes you can sign some data for your benchmarking code. In `sp-io` there is the function [`crypto::ecdsa_sign`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1b1a5e12c0e391c7ed4e3ffa332eb2fe928d257f/primitives/io/src/lib.rs#L904-L909). You can use [`crypto::ecdsa_generate`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1b1a5e12c0e391c7ed4e3ffa332eb2fe928d257f/primitives/io/src/lib.rs#L892) to generate you some public/private key to use for signing.

BTW: All of the things I mentioned above are also available through the [`RuntimePublic`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1b1a5e12c0e391c7ed4e3ffa332eb2fe928d257f/primitives/application-crypto/src/traits.rs#L94-L123) trait.

So, your code using this trait would look like this:

```
use sp_application_crypto::ecdsa::Public;

let public = Public::generate_pair(sp_core::testing::ECDSA, None);
public.sign(sp_core::testing::ECDSA, "my message").unwrap();
```

While `sp_core::testing::ECDSA` being the `KeyTypeId`. If you already have a custom `KeyTypeId` for your application, you can use this.

Comment: In my case I also had to add a benchmark where clause `where_clause { where T::Public : From<sp_core::ecdsa::Public> }` in order to use that key in place where `T::Public` is expected

Comment: You can also require that your public type implements the `RuntimePublic` trait.

Comment: @bkchr How do you resolve the key store error that comes up when you use this in benchmarking i.e `thread 'benchmarking::<>' panicked at 'No keystore' associated for the current context!' `

Comment: The `KeyStore` is being registered by the benchmarking cli. Maybe you are using some old version where this wasn't the case? Which Polkadot bran are you using?

Comment: Am using `branch = "polkadot-v0.9.42"`

Comment: When do you get this error? When running the benchmarking or when running the benchmarking tests?

Comment: I get this error When running the benchmarking tests but the benchmarking builds work without any errors

Comment: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/3c71aa160b8ee594aecf924c66dcadbb8b8c8cdc/frame/nfts/src/mock.rs#L137 you need to register the extension for your test extension.